# CakePHP Making a form to be global with validation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

My application has contacts controller with add action which able to post contacts message to the database table *comments*. It works fine with its validation.
Now I want to use the add view (The contacts form) as a global form to be rendered in all pages of the application.

I know, to do that, I have to make an element contains the form (or the add view) as follows:

elements/contact.ctp

```
<div class="panel">
    <h4><?php echo __('contact'); ?></h4>
<?php echo $form->create('Contact',array('action'=>'index', 'class' => ''));?>
<?php echo $form->input('name', array('size' => 45, 'class' => 'input-text', 'label' => array( 'text' => __('name',true).'<sup>*</sup>'), 'error' => array('class' => 'error', 'wrap' => 'small')));?>
<?php echo $form->input('email', array('size' => 45, 'class' => 'input-text', 'label' => array('text' => __('email',true).'<sup>*</sup>'), 'error' => array('class' => 'error', 'wrap' => 'small')));?>
<?php echo $form->input('subject', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => array(null => __('choose subject',true), 'g' => __('general', true), 'r' => __('report', true)), 'class' => 'input-text', 'label' => array('text' => __('subject', true).'<sup>*</sup>'),'error' => array('class' => 'error', 'wrap' => 'small'))); ?>
<?php echo $form->input('content', array('class' => 'input-text', 'style' => 'height: 140px', 'title' => __('message', true),  'label' => array('text' => __('message',true).'<sup>*</sup>'), 'error' => array('class' => 'error', 'wrap' => 'small')));?>
<?php //echo $fck->load('Contact.message','Mini'); ?>
<span>    
<?php
App::import('Vendor','FoxCaptcha', array('file' => 'Fox_captcha.php'));
       $cap = new Fox_captcha(120,30,5);

                       $cap->image_dir = $html->url('/').'img/';

      $cap->lines_amount = 13;
       $cap->en_reload = $html->image('reload.png', array('alt' => __('reload', true), 'title' => __('reload the captcha', true), 'id' => 'frel', 'style' => 'vertical-align:middle'));

?>
</span>
<div>    
<span class="display:inline"><?php echo $cap->make_it('HTML');?></span>
<?php echo $form->input('vcode', array('size' => 45, 'class' => 'small input-text', 'label' => array('text' => __('captcha', true).'<sup>*</sup>'), 'error' => array('class' => 'error', 'wrap' => 'small')));?>
</div>



<?php echo $form->submit(__('send',true), array('class' => 'nice medium radius white button'));?>

<?php echo $form->end();?>
<div class="alert-box warning"><?php echo __('fields label with * are required');?></div>
</div>
```

The problem is: When I use this form from any page (for example posts/view/22) it submits to contacts/add. **I want after submit posts/view/22 is rendered with any validation message triggered.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this requirement without Ajax and JSON. It includes submitting the form with Ajax to the contacts controller index action with event handler component activated and then check isAjax then render JSON output retrieved by the post's view and then populates the results.